# React Redux FireStore - Changes in FireStore collection does not reflect on my screen unless I refresh

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux, google-cloud-firestore, react-redux

I use React with Redux and Firebase. Here is one of the functions from my Action.js

```
 export const loadItemsInCategory = (categoryId) => {
        return (dispatch) => {
            let itemsArray = [];
            firestoreService.getItemsInCategory(categoryId)
            .then(updatedGroceryList => {
                itemsArray = updatedGroceryList;
                console.log(`category id is ${categoryId}`)
                dispatch(loadItemsInCategoryHelper(categoryId, itemsArray))
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
        }
    }
```

It's a normal FireStore query. Here is what happens in `firestoreService.getItemsInCategory(categoryId)`

```
export const getItemsInCategory = async (categoryId) => {
  console.log(`firebase category id is ${categoryId}`)
  const snapshot = await db.collection('Item').where('category', '==', categoryId).get()
  return snapshot.docs.map(doc => {console.log("called");return {id: doc.id, ...doc.data()}});
}
```

Right now, my application shows the list of items in the given Category. However, the list does not get updated when a new Item is added to the category by someone else. In other words, additions in FireStore collection does not reflect on my screen unless I refresh the page.

How can I code my webapp in such a way that any change on the FireStore end gets reflected on my webapp?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what's the value of snapshot?

Comment: The variable "snapshot" contains the documents from the collection I believe

Answer (score 1):

Your code is doing a one-time query with `get()`.  Queries made like this are not realtime.  They don't refresh.

If you want to receive updates to your query in realtime, you should follow the [documentation for realtime queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen).  Instead of using get(), you will use `onSnapshot()`.  And instead of getting a promise, you will attach a listener callback that will be invoked whenever there is a change in the results of the query.  Because of these differences, your code will look drastically different.